# My Coleman CT200U, has white smoke and what seems to be oil coming out of the exhaust ,

Tags: small-engine

My Coleman CT200U, has white smoke and what seems to be oil coming out of the  exhaust , would this be a piston ring issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The usual causes of white or blue smoke and oil coming out of the exhaust are:

1. As you noted, worn or broken piston rings.
2. Worn or damaged valve guides or stems.
3. Excess oil in the crankcase.
4. Oil in the fuel.
5. Scored or damaged cylinder wall.